# How to query if two subtables from two different tables are identical in SQL?

Tags: sql, db2

Given this table X

```
id#     val1    val2    val3     val4
1000    Alice   A       France   Wed
1001    Alice   B       France   Thurs
1002    Alice   C       France   Fri
1003    Alice   D       France   Sat
```

And this table Y

```
id#     val1    val2    val3     val4
2000    Bob     A       France   Wed
2001    Bob     B       France   Thurs
2002    Bob     C       France   Fri
2003    Bob     D       France   Sat
```

How can I compare Table X and Table Y in SQL query? That is, how can I check if these are equal and to return true? (It might seem dumb to say they are equal, of course they are not) But what my question is, basically even if the id# and val1 are different, these two tables are still identical when comparing val2, val3 and val4.

Of course we can just say, compare each tuple `(val2, val3, val4)` `WHERE X.val1 = 'Alice' AND Y.val1 = 'Bob'`. That's easy. But well, what about if I wish to extend it in a more general sense. For instance, you have a list of val1 values and for all those val1 values where `(val2, val3, val4)` that match, then display them all of them in the schema `(X.val1, Y.val1)`.

Is there a way I could do this (by just querying and without making new tables)? (P.S. pardon my bad english, it's not my first language).

(By the way, I attempted it, but it doesn't seem right:

```
SELECT X.val1, Y.val1
FROM Table X, Table Y
WHERE X.val1 < Y.val1
  AND (X.val2, X.val3, X.val4) = (Y.val2, Y.val3, Y.val4)
```

EDIT: Suppose I expanded the tables X and Y.

Table X:

```
id#     val1    val2    val3     val4
1000    Alice   A       France   Wed
1001    Alice   B       France   Thurs
1002    Alice   C       France   Fri
1003    Alice   D       France   Sat
1004    Cindy   E       Japan    Mon
1005    Cindy   F       Japan    Tues
1006    Cindy   G       Japan    Wed
1007    Cindy   H       Japan    Thurs
```

Table Y:

```
id#     val1    val2    val3     val4
2000    Bob     A       France   Wed
2001    Bob     B       France   Thurs
2002    Bob     C       France   Fri
2003    Bob     D       France   Sat
2004    Fred    E       Japan    Mon
2005    Fred    F       Japan    Tues
2006    Fred    G       Japan    Wed
```

Now notice that if you comnpare Alice and Bob, they're identical "subtables" with their `(val2, val3, val4)` schemas being identical, as well as the number of such are the same. But Cindy's and Fred's are not as Cindy has 4 tuples and Fred has 3 only. So Alice and Bob would be part of the answer table but Cindy and Fred are not. How do I write a query in such a way that I would be able to compare Alice and Bob, then Alice and Fred, then Cindy and Bob, and then Cindy, and Fred. And among those four combos, only Alice and Bob gets returned.

Many thanks to those who have answered. I still am self-learning SQL in DB2 for the first time and answers here are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A full outer join can also do this:

```
select X.val1, Y.val1,
       case 
         when x.val2 is null then 'Row not in X'
         when y.val2 is null then 'Row not in Y'
         else 'Values are different'
       end as status
from table_x x
  full join table_y y on (X.val2, X.val3, X.val4) = (Y.val2, Y.val3, Y.val4)
where x.val2 is null -- rows missing in X
   or y.val2 is null -- rows missing in Y
   or x.val1 <> y.val1;
```

This assumes that `val2` is defined as `not null`

Answer (score 0):

The `EXCEPT` operator might be the simplest option here:

```
SELECT val2, val3, val4
FROM X
EXCEPT
SELECT val2, val3, val4
FROM Y
```

This would output any records in `X` whose `val2-val4` values do not match another record in `Y`.  You could also do the `EXCEPT` in reverse direction to find records in `Y` not matching to anything in `X`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The OP tagged with DB2 I believe.  What is the problem?

Comment: So DB2 is Oracle?

Comment: Bad documentation refs for DB2, sorry, answer updated.

Comment: From my edit, then would I still be able to do the same way?

Comment: @M.Fire My answer can still give you insight into what you want, but look at the answer by Horse for a better option.